# Sending dynamically variable from .ts to .html in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a grid and I want to sending class condition from `.ts` file. I achieve this with code `myClassCondition = 5 < 6 ? 'bg-red' : null;` like below. But, I want like below with "col" and "rowData". Is gave me compilation error because there is no "col" and "rowData" in `.ts` file. How can I achieve this?

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of myColumns" class="ui-resizable-column">
      <span [ngClass]="myClassCondition"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

This working perfectly.

```
myClassCondition = 5 < 6 ? 'bg-red' : null;
```

But I want like this.

```
myClassCondition = col.field == 'studentAge' && rowData.[col.field] < 6 ? 'bg-red' : null;
```

I tried this but also not worked.

```
myClassCondition : string = "col.field == 'studentAge' && rowData.[col.field] < 6 ? 'bg-red' : null";
```

Comment: What should be the value when `col.field != 'studentAge'`?

Comment: It can be null or string.empty.It's no matter. My problem is access to "col" and "rowData"

Comment: You could use a function with a `col` and `rowData` parameter instead of the string property `myClassCondition` (which btw. isn't a condition but just a string value).

Comment: Sorry. But I couldn't understand exactly your want to telling. And what btw means? @Henry

Comment: I found btw means :) "By The Way". And now I understand that, you want to say like that I marked answer of DilanTharaka. @Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ts file, Instead of having a variable to a decide class, use a function

```
getClassCondition(col, rowData)
{
 return col.field == 'studentAge' && rowData.[col.field] < 6 ? 'bg-red' : null;
}
```

and in your template, call that functions to get class,

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of myColumns" class="ui-resizable-column">
      <span [ngClass]="getClassCondition(col, rowData)"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Since you have a seperate component called `app-grid` and the logic to define class name depends on the hosting component, do something like this,
In the ts file of your `app-grid` component, define input to get the function that can return required value,

```
@Input() logic: any;
```

and change `getClassCondition` function in `app-grid` component to something like following,

```
getClassCondition(col, rowData)
{
 return logic(col,rowData);
}
```

and in the hosting component, define the actual function to define class. In that components' ts file define it,

```
logic = function(col,rowData){
 return col.field == 'studentAge' && rowData.[col.field] < 6 ? 'bg-red' : null; // change this implementation in different components
}
```

And in that components' template file, send that function as an input

```
<app-grid [logic]="logic"></app-grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DilanTharaka . But, in my real scenario, this html is a global component.  And my page call it like <app-grid></app-grid>.  So, my `getClassCondition` method will be in my parent component and can't access from inner to parent.

Comment: so, why don't you implement `getClassCondition` function inside `app-grid` components' ts file ?

Comment: Because every page has different condition, different columnName, different types etc.  (for example other page can be `return col.field == 'universityName' && rowData.[col.field].length > 50 ? 'bg-purple' : null;`) @DilanTharaka

Comment: I changed my answer, check that out

Comment: Thanks a lot @DilanTharaka. It worked perfectly.. You saved my a lot of time. But, I will try this by `output` instead of `input`. Because, output can be better way for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of myColumns" class="ui-resizable-column">
      <span [ngClass]="myClassCondition(rowData,col.field)"> {{rowData[col.field]}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>

myClassCondition(rowData,col_field) {
    if(check your condition){
        return 'bg-red';
     }
}
```

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid what Pakkiyaraj is trying to say is instead of using variable you can make a function so that you can send both the variable from your html and then in you component you can have the access of both the variables using that function and can check your condition what yours is not working as you described in your question

Comment: Thanks for your replies . But, in my real scenario, this html is a global component.  And my page call it like <app-grid></app-grid>.  So, my `myClassCondition()` method will be in my parent component and can't access from inner to parent. @Pakkiyaraj